# LAPACK in fortran90 eigenvalues

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am in trouble understanding how LAPACK zgeev routine for finding eigenvalues works. I have read documentation and MKL example from [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/zgeev_ex.f.htm)

I want to do my own example in fortran90 style. Here is my code:

```
program test_zgeev
implicit none
integer, parameter :: n = 2, lwmax = 1000
integer :: lwork, info, i
real(8) :: rwork(n*2) 
complex(16) :: w(n), work(lwmax), vl(n), vr(n), a(n, n)
integer :: lda, ldvl, ldvr
lda = n; ldvl = n; ldvr = n

a(1, 1) = 1.0d0; a(1, 2) = -1.0d0
a(2, 1) = 5.0d0; a(2, 2) = -1.0d0

lwork = lwmax

CALL ZGEEV( 'Vectors', 'Vectors', N, A, LDA, W, VL, LDVL, &
            VR, LDVR, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, INFO )

do i = 1, n
    write(*, *) w(i)
enddo

end program
```

It compiles and formally runs but eigenvalues are wrong, I get (1, 0) (0, 0) instead of correct (0, 2) (0, -2). When I try to use the same matrix directly in the MKL example (fortran 77) it works correctly. Therefore, there is a mistake somewhere due to my misunderstanding of differences between f77 and f90. Can you please help me to find it?

Comment: Welcome. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Please anybody re-tag the question so that I can use mark it as a duplicate..

Comment: Indeed, it is the duplicate. You can mark it yourself by clicking on close. Or, *please*, [edit] the question for tag [tag:fortran] and I will do it.

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried to compile the code and indeed, it gives the correct answer with proper double precision complex.